# Objc & Metal Compute depth texture in cube form result to strange depth map in other five faces except the +X depth texture

Tags: objective-c, textures, metal

I am implementing point light dynamic shadow using Metal in my project. The point light shadow requires a **depth cube texture (depth texture from 6 different directions)** to compute shadow maps and perform depth tests from all directions.

Currently, I tried as the sample code [Reflection With Layer Selection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/reflections_with_layer_selection?language=objc) from Apple's documentation pages, but the depth cube texture seems not correct in other five directions except +X direction.

---

*[ Sorry I can't post image here. Instead I uploaded images to github, so please refer to the following links >.< ]*

In Xcode debug view, step into Reflections Command buffer -> ReflectionPass -> DrawActors 1 to view the depth cube texture (the selected one in right panel):
https://github.com/kiorisyshen/RepoForStackOverflow/blob/master/metalDepthCubeTexture_01.png

The +X direction seems correct:
https://github.com/kiorisyshen/RepoForStackOverflow/blob/master/metalDepthCubeTexture_02.png

But the other directions look strange (here I only uploaded +Z direction):
https://github.com/kiorisyshen/RepoForStackOverflow/blob/master/metalDepthCubeTexture_03.png

---

Are there settings should be cared about or actions should be taken to get correct depth cube texture? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify your target platform, GPU, and OS version? I'm not seeing these artifacts on a 2016 MacBook Pro with Radeon Pro 460 graphics on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The platform I used to run the sample code is Mac mini (2018) with Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, and it is running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G95) @warrenm